# Does Google Analytics content experiments track conversions that happen off the original landing page?

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page

I am running a Google Analytics content experiment and some of my landing pages have links to other pages on my site that also have my form.

If a user clicks away from the original landing page that they were redirected to for the experiment and then submits my form from a different page, are those conversions counted as conversions from the original landing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those off page conversions are counted as well, **as long as the Google Analytics goal stays the same** (eg. all those forms have the same Thank you page).

If those other forms have other Analytics goals associated with them, then they are not counted.